# Restart application within AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there any way to restart an application on a button click using AS3? I want to return the state of the program back to the way it is when it is first ran as I tried calling a method that removes the children from the `Sprite` layers they are added to but I was getting errors when doing it that way.

I can't remove all children from the `Sprite` layers as there are certain things on the layers that I want to remove and there are things that I don't want to remove.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I restart flash application with actionscript 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799462/how-do-i-restart-flash-application-with-actionscript-3)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you have to create your own cleanup functions. This is obviously very difficult to get working correctly at the end of a project, so I typically work on this in parallel with the actual application. It might look something like:

```
public function cleanup():void
{
    // Remove listeners.
    // Empty arrays.
    // Remove children.
    // etc
}
```

There's not really an 'inbuilt' way to do this, so at this stage you've a long process of debugging to go through while trying to cover everything off yourself.

Comment: Yeah that was my biggest issue, having to go backwards and figure out what to remove from where, debugging errors etc.